# How can I set numbers that equals days of month

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

First of all, I'm sorry if im explaining it too bad, but I'm at least trying...

I have a table with checkboxes, https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0xPv.png
code is like that:

```
<td>
<?php 
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $k = $date;
    for($k=8; $k<=31; $k++){
?>
</td>
<td>
<?php 
        for($k=1; $k<=31; $k++){
?>
<td>
```

How can I get change these numbers to calendar numbers, because I want it to begin not with 1, but with the day that is today.

I hope i did ask a question right, if not, please, feel free to comment for more details

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: [`for ($k=date('j') ....`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: You can try `for( $i=date('j'); $i <= date('t'); $i++ )echo $i;`

Comment: https://3v4l.org/Ss4Aq

Comment: @RamRaider Thank you, you helped me a lot <3

Comment: 1 more thing, I want other days to show also, but be readonly or something like that @RamRaider